# ¿Como hacer una function para contabilizar días hábiles entre un rango de fechas?

Tags: javascript

Buen día, quiero validar que a partir de una fecha de inicio se sumen ciertos días eso ya lo hace pero la validación empieza en que no sume días sábados y domingos o días festivos, estos días festivos los tengo almacenados en una base de datos, tengo la idea pero no logro aterrizar la haciendo un contador de día por día hasta tener el numero que se ingreso.

Comment: si de 1/1/2000 al 20/1/2000 hay 20 días. y tienes 10 festivos. 20 - 10 = 10 días. Sólo tienes que hacer un endpoint hacia tu backend que te devuelva los días festivos.

Comment: Hola, una consulta ¿estás preguntando para Java o JavaScript? o ¿te es indistinto en qué lenguaje sea?

Comment: Hola, la pregunta es para  JavaScript

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias por esa observación, Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Esto serviría para determinar los días de semana, 0 y 7 del getDay indican Domingo y Sábado respectivamente.

```js
var fecha = new Date();
switch(fecha.getDay()){
  case 0:
  console.log("Domingo");
  break;
case 1:
  console.log("Lunes");
  break;
case 2:
  console.log("Martes");
  break;
case 3:
  console.log("Miércoles");
  break;
case 4:
  console.log("Jueves");
  break;
case 5:
  console.log("Viernes");
  break;
case 6:
  console.log("Sábado");
  break;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Contar días hábiles Java

Este es un ejemplo que te regresa el numero de días hábiles laborables de lunes a viernes, no tomando en cuenta sábados, domingos y días festivos por ejemplo 1 de enero, 25 de diciembre los cuales agregaremos a una lista de fechas no laborables, y obtenemos las los días hábiles dado en un rango de fechas, fecha inicial y fecha final. [Ejemplo](http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/wp/2016/12/22/contar-dias-habiles-en-java/)

```
package mx.com.softmolina;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author SoftMolina
 */
public class ValidacionFechas {

   public int diasHabiles(Calendar fechaInicial, Calendar fechaFinal, List<Date> listaFechasNoLaborables) {
       int diffDays = 0;
       boolean diaHabil = false;
       //mientras la fecha inicial sea menor o igual que la fecha final se cuentan los dias
       while (fechaInicial.before(fechaFinal) || fechaInicial.equals(fechaFinal)) {

          if (!listaFechasNoLaborables.isEmpty()) {
              for (Date date : listaFechasNoLaborables) {
                  Date fechaNoLaborablecalendar = fechaInicial.getTime();
                  //si el dia de la semana de la fecha minima es diferente de sabado o domingo
                  if (fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && !fechaNoLaborablecalendar.equals(date)) {
                      //se aumentan los dias de diferencia entre min y max
                      diaHabil = true;
                  } else {
                      diaHabil = false;
                      break;
                  }
              }
          } else {
              if (fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
                  //se aumentan los dias de diferencia entre min y max
                  diffDays++;
              }
          }
          if (diaHabil == true) {
          diffDays++;
          }
          //se suma 1 dia para hacer la validacion del siguiente dia.
          fechaInicial.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
     }
     return diffDays;
  }

}
```

Comment: La pregunta menciona explícitamente JavaScript